# how to release copy property added using category in objective C?

Tags: memory-management, retain, objective-c-category

I have added a copy property to UITableViewCell using category as shown below

```
NSString const *key = @"CellSelectedBlockKey";

@interface UITableViewCell (CellSelectionBlock)
@property (nonatomic, copy) CellSelectedBlock cellSelectedBlock;
@end

@implementation UITableViewCell (CellSelectionBlock)

- (void)setCellSelectedBlock:(void(^)(UITableView *table, NSIndexPath *indexpath))cellSelectedBlock
{
    objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &key, cellSelectedBlock, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}

- (CellSelectedBlock)cellSelectedBlock
{
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &key);
}
@end
```

How would I clear memory (release), this property as I cannot overite dealloc method for this.

I'll appreciate any help on this. Any suggestion on best way to add property to an existing class without subclassing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An associated object set with a strong-reference associated object policy (`OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN`, `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC`, `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY`, or `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC`) are automatically released when a new value is set (or `nil` is set to clear) for the same key, or when the parent object is deallocated, just like with `retain`/`copy` properties, or with a strong reference in ARC.